# Istio Gateway resource created but not listed in any kubernetes namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

I'm installing the following Gateway resouce in my GKE cluster:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: default-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: istio-ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      name: http-web
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP2
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

With command `kubectl apply -f gateway.yaml` (have also tried with `kubectl create`)

Output: `gateway.networking.istio.io/default-gateway created`

But when I try to list it in `k9s` no gateway is visible:

[image]

Same result if I try to list all resources in all namespaces no gateway created:

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```

Have tried searching also in same namespace `istio-system` but no results.

tried also istioctl but all seems in order:

```
istioctl analyze -n istio-system                

✔ No validation issues found when analyzing namespace: istio-system.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing in k9s is a different `Gateway` crd, probably `gateways.gateway.networking.k8s.io`.

Running `kubectl get gateways.networking.istio.io` should show you the created resource.

Comment: glad to help, would be nice if you could approve the answer

Comment: SOverflow says I must wait around 5 min, I'll do it in bit, greatly appreciate your help.